# Why do JSF variables in Richfaces components not resolve?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, composite-component

I'm using Richfaces 4.3.3.

I'm having a composite widget. I pass a parameter/attribute, which is prints correctly within that widget. If I want to add this variable (integer) to a `<rich:popupPanel>`, the value resolves to 0 (default value for integers).

```
<rich:popupPanel id="popupEditor_#{cc.attrs.pubId}">
    #{cc.attrs.pubId}
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Intresting enough, the value within the tag, resolves correct. Is that a phase listener issue? If yes, how do I overcome this problem - stil using rich faces components?

Comment: Have you tried putting it inside `<h:outputText>`? (Or <span>, something that is supposed to contain text)

Comment: In the future, before you make some strong statements pointing to a specific suspect based on hastily made observations ("this does not work in RichFaces components"), please exclude it first from being the cause by replacing `<rich:popupPanel>` by e.g. `<h:panelGroup>`. The statement in your title is namely utterly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, carefully read this: [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Summarized, EL expressions in `id` attributes are evaluated during view build time. In your particular case, based on the symptoms, the `#{cc.attrs.pubId}` seems to be available during view render time only, for example because it's definied by `var` of an iterating JSF UI component, or because it's definied as a bean property which is set after view build time only, etc.

You need to head to a different solution. I can't tell that in detail as you didn't tell anything about the concrete functional requirement for which you thought that *this* would be the solution. But, to the point, you've 2 options:

1. Make sure that any EL variables in `id` (and `binding`) attribute are available during view build time. For example, use `<c:forEach>` instead of `<ui:repeat>`.
2. Put it on a plain HTML element. It's evaluated during view render time.

   ```html
   <rich:popupPanel id="popupEditor">
       <div id="#{cc.attrs.pubId}">
           ...
       </div>
   </rich:popupPanel>
   ```

Or perhaps you don't need it at all and you simply overthought a solution without actually having a concrete problem. When your composites are designed properly, you should have **no need** for a dynamic ID inside the composite.

```html
<rich:popupPanel id="popupEditor">
    ...
</rich:popupPanel>
```

JSF already takes care of it automatically as composite components inherently extend from `NamingContainer`. You just have to give the `<my:composite>` itself a fixed ID instead.

Comment: Once again, you are assuming right. This code snippet is from a composite, which is iterated by a ui:repeat. So, as you said, the ID is not available at view render time. Thanks for enlightening this situation.